# How does Zoro's sword technique work?

Tags: one-piece

A lot of times, Zoro uses his swords to cut down far away objects without any physical contact. How does that work?

Comment: I'm not a big one piece fan, but in anime in general that usually happens by the shockwaves travelling through the air rapidly, causing anything in a wide arc and range to be sliced. Obviously, it'd take no less than Son Goku's strength to pull it off, so not very realistic.

Comment: That would be similar to Temari's jutsus using her fan

Comment: @ChetterHummin: Not exactly. Temari uses *wind element chakra*, which creates long and thin lines of high speed vibration. That acts like a chainsaw which cuts through any object.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I can't find screenshots but whenever you see blue things travelling from Zoro's swords, those are shockwaves that can cut anything, even buildings.

That's what he does, he sends a sort of shockwave. We obviously know that a human can't pull a sword (or another object) to create such a strong shockwave.

But if you think about it, if you move a wooden stick but towards the ground (as when you hit the ball in golf), you'll cause the air to move following that movement (adding various turbulences) that will affect whatever small is on the ground (e.g. sand).

Zoro's attacks are something similar to that but only much stronger. It's not realistic, but then, almost nothing on One Piece is realistic.

Comment: To use a videogame example, the logic behind Zoro's slashes is the same logic behind Guile's Sonic Booms.

Comment: I believe the description you're looking for that Zoro's techniques not only cut but also launch projectiles of compressed air.

Comment: @Krazer Yeah there's also that one! :D

Comment: But when he faught Brook's zomby, the blue something you stated as shokwafes set his enemy on (likewise blue) fire. Isn't that indicating, that it is either some kind of energy/ chi/ chakra or nothing but highly compressed and thus hot air?